# Artifact Registry Plugin and microdnf

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redhat-ubi

Is the Artifact Registry Plugin (`ar-plugin`) compatible with [`microdnf`](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/microdnf)?

We're trying to use Cloud Builder with `redhat/ubi8-minimal` which uses a slimmed down version of `dnf` named `microdnf`.  It has the same commands as `dnf` so we hoped it would work alike, however we just can't get authenticated for our private repository. I'm now suspecting that since it "uses `libdnf` and hence doesn't require Python" the plugin may not work.

Answer (score 0):

No, Artifact Registry  does not officially support microdnf so it might not be compatible.However,  the plugin has official support for dnf. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/os-packages/rpm/configure)

If you would like to see this supported in the future, you can file a feature request for it following these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/getting-support#featurerequest). Please note that feature requests do not provide any implementation guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ar-plugin` doesn't work with `microdnf`, however installing the plugin installs `dnf`, so we just switched to `dnf` at that point.

The authentication problem persisted however. In the end we found how to turn debug on for the plugin and found it was timing out on the metadata server request.  We eventually found the solution was to enable the [`cloudbuild` network](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#network) in the docker build step.